# Saving Google Doc as PDF isn't showing all images

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to set up a Google Sheet that populates fields and inserts images in a Google Doc template and downloads it as a PDF. I'm having some trouble with the images part - in particular, when I download as a PDF the images aren't showing past the second page. The following links replicate the problem - the first link is the Google Doc and the second link downloads as a PDF.

Link 1 - Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ybzqiVzRdanawEl-CHO1E4ifueXb8BHvFKP5Beat6-U/edit?usp=sharing

Link 2 - PDF Download: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ybzqiVzRdanawEl-CHO1E4ifueXb8BHvFKP5Beat6-U/export?format=pdf

As shown, the first link contains 3 pages of images, while the PDF shows a blank third page. Is there any way that I can get around this, in particular when using Google Scripts to download as a PDF?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see what you mean because I can see all three images.

Comment: All 3 images in the PDF? When I click on the second link I still only see the first 2 images and a blank third page - I'll try resetting a few things. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Can confirm. 3 images in 3 pages in PDF are seen.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the image isn't clipping into the margin.

While it looks like the bug you were experiencing in the above doc is now fixed, I had a similar problem and discovered that the image was just barely too wide, causing Google to remove it completely from the saved pdf.